# projects with jaxb in netbreans are throwing an error if netbeans is executed with graalvm 22+

Tags: java, netbeans, graalvm

Today i've upgraded my local jdk from `graalvm-ce-java17-22.2.0` to `graalvm-ce-java19-22.3.0` because the runtime crashed a few times in my debug sessions.
Then i wanted to run my netbeans project, which failed with the following error message:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class FQN-OF-MAIN-CLASS in module jdk.internal.vm.compiler
C:\...\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1418: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\...\nbproject\build-impl.xml:924: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\...\nbproject\build-impl.xml:943: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Because the project was running before the upgrade, I've closed netbeans, deleted the netbeans-cache, updated the environment variables to point to the new jdk (wasnt neccessary before), changed netbeans conf so that netbeans is running with the new jdk too and started netbeans again.

same error. creating another runable class in this project or executing a single class instead of the hole project results in the same error too. creating a new project running a hello-world-file succeeds. also, in the "problematic" project, if i hit clean-and-build and run the resulting jar from command line thats works well, but netbeans seems to have a problem debugging/running the project from within the ide. also restored `nbproject/build-impl.xml` and `nbproject/project.xml` from repository, but still getting the same error. also tried going back to v22.2 but now i get the same error there too.

So I assume that I messed it up somewhere, but don't know where I should start looking? The error points to the ide generated ant script which i havent touched, older projects and newly created projects are running fine...

any ideas?

netbeans 15
windows 10 22H2 x64
graalvm-ce-java19-22.3.0

EDIT 1:
It does not seem related to source code. removed every file from `/src` and created a new class `test/NewClass.java` with a main that also produces the error.

EDIT 2:
Tried `graalvm-ce-java17-22.3.0`, but got the same error.

EDIT 3:
Could track it down (a bit), it's somehow related to JAXB bindings. Creating a new project, changing Platform to 1.8 with StandardJDK, adding a JAXB-Binding and running an empty main class works. Changing the Platform to 16/17/19 with GraalVM produces the error. Reverting back to 1.8. resolves the error. Of course the problematic project makes use of JAXB, but its running with GraalVM 16/17 for quite some time without producing the error. Fun fact, netbeans is adding a JAXB version 2.3.5 which seems not public availiable on the maven repository.

EDIT 4:
JAXB itself seems to be not the primary problem, but its related. If netbeans is executed with the standard JDK 1.8 or GraalVM 21.1 JAXB works in all kind of projects, regardless of the platform the project is executed with.
***But if I change the JDK netbeans is started with to GraalVM 22 or newer, then projects containg JAXB are producing the above error.***
Since JAXB in Netbeans 15 works with GraalVM 21 but not newer versions I think that probably be a problem with GraalVM rather than netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

Does Netbeans support JDK19? You might want to try `graalvm-ce-java17-22.3.0`, i.e. upgrade GraalVM version but stay on the JDK17 line

Comment: Thats a good idea. can't find anything on the netbeans page which jdk versions are supported...? But I am pretty sure that netbeans recognized the platform as JDK 19 (netbeans is started with the same jdk and thats the first platform netbeans offers for projects, the one it is started with) and also offered a source code switch in the project settings with "source 19". But I'll give it a try on monday when I am back to work, don't have access to the project from home.

Comment: tried `graalvm-ce-java17-22.3.0`, still getting the same error :(